# MYSQL reading a raw CSV data

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

Out of curiosity, I often get raw data CSV from my colleague, Sometimes I go over the raw data, which MySQL is unable to read data like Date or timestamp and Currency,

Example of timestamp `2018.03.05 18:38:41` then I export it to MySQL using the workbench, then they displayed `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as MYSQL prefer using their own datatype

I have looked it on MySQL Reference

- The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
  parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
  HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
  '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Also, another question on money (using DECIMAL(13,2)) as I get euro format like `35,72` as I have to change into `35.72` if I ignore it as MySQL will pick up on only `35.00` and leave 72 cent out of it.

It can be a pain for me to check all over CSV text for date and money.I did ask Colleague about this CSV, He said he got export CSV from their software as he cannot modify it on the software.

Is there a way to can Mysql can read and translation to correct type of data field. I am not sure if Workbench can do it.

Comment: You should make a pre treatment of your data with some script language... Or help your colleague export the data in the format you want

Comment: I would stage as varchars into one table then convert on way into another table, then push out the data from there in the converted format

Comment: 'pre-treatment of your data with some script language' I was thinking of this too, I decided to not put on this topic as not sure if it's off the topic. I was thinking to build a basic PHP page, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp format shouldn't be a problem. I tested and it worked fine.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

> MySQL permits a “relaxed” format for values specified as strings, in which any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts.

The money format has to be assigned to a string variable, then you can set your money column based on an expression that parses the string.

This is an example in the mysql client, but you can do the same thing in MySQL Workbench:

```
mysql> create table test (id int, d datetime, money decimal(13,2));

mysql> load data local infile 'test.csv' into table test 
   (id, d, @n) 
   set money = @n + substring_index(@n, ',', 2)/100;

mysql> select * from test;
+------+---------------------+-------+
| id   | d                   | money |
+------+---------------------+-------+
|  123 | 2018-03-05 18:38:41 | 35.35 |
+------+---------------------+-------+
```

---

Re your comment:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('05.03.2018 18:38:41 UTC', '%m.%d.%Y %k:%i:%s UTC') as d;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2018-05-03 18:38:41 |
+---------------------+
```

Unfortunately there's no date format code for timezone, but if you can rely on it always being UTC in the data you receive, you can use UTC literally in the format string, as I show above.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: You are right with a timestamp format issue, Another Question if you don't mind, If I get raw CSV data with this Date '05.03.2018 18:38:41 UTC'  how we should deal with it.